# IPhone : View property on a Xib, is it special?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I can't believe I am stuck on this but here goes.

I have a viewController which I am trying to add to another viewController via the addsubview property (basic as) however I am not doing viewController.view but viewController.myView1.

I basically have 2 root views on the xib (both with outlets) however I don't want to wire up the view property of the xib because I want to choose which view to show.

I can't get it to appear!  Is the view property some sort of special hook?

I can't see why addsubview:mysubview should not work?

Some examples seem to use 2 different xib's but that seems a overkill

Comment: Just seeing if I follow you. In your xib you have something like myView1 and myView2. You add your other view controller to it by adding its view as a subview to myView1. But neither myView1 and the added subView are showing. Is that it?

Comment: No, i have the xib as you say but I am adding that xib to another view controller and neither of the myView1/2 will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Apple say a viewcontroller should be used for a whole screen full of views - (but I guess iPad container views are different).

I guess you're wanting to only use one of the viewcontrollers at once. In which case you shouldn't be using subview - just create the viewcontroller programmatically, create the view, assign the view to the viewcontroller's view property and then add the viewcontroller to the window or navigation bar.

and, in your viewcontroller:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibOne bundle:nil];
```

might be what you want - it allows you to use multiple nibs with a single viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Can you NSLog your `viewController.myView1` before add it as a subview? Is it `nil` or not?

If it's `nil`, try to add this line before your `addSubview:` method:

`[viewController view];`

Note: The **viewController** I am talking about is the same viewController which have two root views `view` and `myView1`.

Comment: This causes a crash instantly with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PLNotificationViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** Call stack at first throw: which we know

Comment: As the exception description said, maybe the outlet of "PLNotificationViewController" nib's view was not set. Would you please check your xib settings again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be good as this is fairly simple and I do it all the time.
Just make sure your outlets are wired properly and that you are synthesizing them and that they are public in your header.